# Rails link_to only hyperlinking part of link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, quotes

I have

```
<%=link_to distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(post.created_at), post %> ago
```

However I want to make 'ago' show up in link as well. Now its something like '[20 minutes](http://example.com) ago,' which kind of looks ugly. I want it to look like [20 minutes ago](http://example.com).'

I tried using #{} with no success and Google search turns out very little, especially since I don't even know what I'm looking for.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This must work:

```
<%= link_to "#{distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(post.created_at)} ago", post %>
```

Don't know why it didn't work for you. Any code samples?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<%= link_to "#{distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(post.created_at)} ago", post %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, the block syntax for long links:

```
<%= link_to post do %>
  <%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(post.created_at) %> ago
<% end %>
```

You could easily add an icon here, for example.

On a side note, it also doesn't add a horizontal scrollbar to StackOverflow's layout :)